# Missing archive file during Progress installation?

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

We are adding additional products to our existing Progress installation. We are installing Client Networking and Query/Results.

During the installation it gives us missing archive file and we click OK to abort the installation.

> Missing archive file `4glcrypt` and `admrtchr`

We follow the steps in the below article

http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P10417

Comment: I added the openedge tag. Simply tagging progress is very broad and wont help the question to find a good audience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be that you've uncompressed the installation-file on a separate platform and perhaps another OS?

This KnowledgeBase entry gives such an example (could apply to other platforms than PA-RISC as below):
http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P158689

> **Cause**
>
> The tar file was being un-compressed on Windows host before copying the files to the PA-RISC host.
>
> **Resolution**
>
> Transfer the files to the proper Operating System before unpacking.

A work around is of course to do a clean install instead of an upgrade.